# Using both &#38; and amp; to represent ampersand in KML?

Tags: kml

I'm looking at the Chicago Open Data Portal's [list of bus stops](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Transportation/CTA-Bus-Stops-KML/fxnt-b8ay), and I see that they've doubly-escaped some, but not all, of their ampersands. In other words, they sometimes encode their ampersands as &#38;amp, and sometimes just as &#38;

The pattern I notice is that they doubly-escape ampersands inside of the description fields, which are fully-fledged HTML documents *inside* of the KML document itself.

Does anyone have any insight on this? Is it a bug in the city data? It doesn't render correctly in Google Earth either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML entity encoding in the Chicago Open Data Portal's list of bus stops in KML is incorrect.

The following KML snippet shows up as `Indiana &amp; 14th Street` in the description balloon of Google Earth not as "Indiana & 14th Street" which was intended.

Example:

```
<Placemark>
    <name>Indiana &#38; 14th Street</name>
    <description>
      <![CDATA[<html xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        ...
        <td>PUBLIC_NAME</td>
        <td>Indiana &#38;amp; 14th Street</td>
        ....
       </html>
      ]]>
    </description>
```

The text `&#38;amp;` is decoded as `&amp;` which by using the CDATA block is shown as-is. To display the "&" in the description then a `&#38;` or `&amp;` (not both) is needed within the CDATA block content. The encoding in the name field is correct since it doesn't have a CDATA tag.

In fact, the KML should use a single [BalloonStyle](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#balloonstyle) to capture the lengthy HTML text in each placemark  with [ExtendedData](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#extendeddata) for specific values (e.g. city, status, public name, etc.) in the placemarks in addition to compressing the file as a KMZ -- this would greatly reduce the 15MB file to a much smaller size.

Here's a tutorial using BalloonStyles and ExtendedData.
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/extendeddata

Here's a description of special entity encoding in KML.
http://kml4earth.appspot.com/kmlErrata.html#encoding